# Understand ACTV mode and the PORT command

Tags: ftp, port, filezilla

I'm the part time FTP server administrator (with no real full-time admin). We currently only allow ACTV mode connections. Some of our clients have had issues with this but for the most part they've been ok using ACTV. For the few who aren't, we've been able to push the data over to their servers from ours.
    there is one client in particular however who is currently having trouble. He is using file-zilla and issuing a PORT command.
    First, does using the PORT command imply that you are in ACTV mode?
    Second is there a way in FileZilla to explicitly change to ACTV mode?
Thanks for the help,
_Ramy

Comment: well...there's further confusion here. snippet from log file in the next comment.

Comment: 10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, PASV
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 501 PASV not allowed.
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, PORT 192,147,57,6,138,19
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 200 Port command successful.
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, RETR FILENAME
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, asked to download 'MASKEDFILENAME' -> 'FILENAME' from 0 --> Access allowed.

Comment: 10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 150 Opening data connection for FILENAME (525060 bytes)
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, finished downloading 'MASKEDFILENAME' -> 'FILENAME' from 0 to 525060 (00:00:01 - 512.754 KBytes/s).
10/05/11 09:32:26, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 226 File sent ok.
10/05/11 09:32:27, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, MDTM FILENAME
10/05/11 09:32:27, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 213 20091005100655
10/05/11 09:32:27, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, PASV
10/05/11 09:32:27, 57139, 192.147.57.6, USER, 501 PASV not allowed.

Comment: sorry it's not very readable - not sure how to properly post a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active mode requires the PORT command. PORT is what tells the server where to connect to on the client in order to open the data channel.

Active FTP breaks when the client is behind NAT, hence Passive is the preferred default in most situations where FTP is used. It is strongly preferable to not use FTP and switch to SFTP.

Comment: ok, really not sure what's happening here. Trying to test FileZilla from the same side of the firewall. I set FileZilla to "fall back to active". I can connect just fine. But when i try to transfer files i see this:
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Starting download of /FILE
Error: Failed to open "FILE" for writing
Error: File transfer failed
Status: Starting download of /FILE
Error: Failed to open "FILE" for writing
Error: File transfer failed
Status: Starting download of /FILE
Error: Failed to open "FILE" for writing
Error: File transfer failed